# Python 2.7 - Codenvy - Debugging issues

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, codenvy

I'm working with Codenvy writing a Google Appengine app, and I have found it to be INSANELY difficult to debug. If there's a syntax error I have to find it manually as the web page that loads when testing give me and error:500. Also, I often want to print but Codenvy doesn't support printing for python (that or I don't understand the correct method). Has anyone else experienced this and able to help?  Perhaps developing in the cloud isn't as easy as I was hoping...

Comment: I think you are always going to loose some capability when not developing locally, your looking at a very immature toolset.

Comment: This is true, but I'm also looking for pretty basic features... hopefully someone will have a solution, even if it's a wonky workaround.

Comment: Printing generally won't work in appengine at all, you need to use logging.

Comment: Reading docs for code envy they only have debug support with java.  This only leaves logging and inspecting the appengine logs.  To be honest I would move your dev locally if your using python.

Comment: @TimHoffman I use the collaboration functions in Codenvy, so moving to local IDE doesn't really help. I already have the IDE set up locally. Working on a project with a friend. I've tried the logging bug and it doesn't seem to be working. Ugh... lame.

Answer (score 1):

https://c9.io/‎

That's the answer. Codenvy just isn't ready yet for real use. Cloud9 IDE is fully functional. All my hopes and desires came true with this site.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that if you go to the Google App Developper Console, there is a menu on the left. Click on App Engine, then click on Logs. There you can see the internal server error (error 500) log, which pretty much tell you what went wrong.